# openerp not loading on localhost

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

Hi I have been working on openerp-7 (win-7)  custom module creation . I have been loading openerp server through localhost:8069 . But today the application failed to start and its generating error " Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8069 " . What should I do now to fix this issue?

Plz help
Hopes for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the OpenERP service is running on your computer. You can verify this by clicking on the Taskbar -> task manager -> Services.
Look for the OpenERP service and start it if it is not running.

A problem might have made it fail to start. There might be errors with your custom module.

I tell you developing custom modules on Window is more tedious than on Linux because you can run the server in terminal mode and view output logged directly on the console

Comment: I want to add func to my button created ion openerp custom module. I as failing to declare functions on clicking the button. Plz help

Comment: post your python here, as well as your xml as it relates to the button; so I will know what the problem is. Thanks

Comment: give me ur id , I will send my proj

Comment: you mean email? peterchibunna*fmguy.com

Comment: can u plz clearly write ur id , I donot understand the domain

Comment: mailed ,  do chk and reply me

Comment: ok. let me work on it and then get back to you, probably tomorrow.

Comment: I want a button that will allow the user to create new fields by himself, Have any idea of how to do this